If formula (the sum is less than 30 then roundup tp 30)
I need a formula for excel.
I have a cell that currently has the following formula, =SUM(G4/30)
I want to add to that formula that if the sum is less than 30 then I need it to be roundup to 30
I can't figure it out

=if(sum(G4/30)<30,30,sum(G4/30))

So:
This should work:
=if(sum(G4/30)<30,30,sum(g4/30))

Updated based on comment:
To keep the answer if zero:
=if(G4=0,0,if(sum(G4/30)<30,30,sum(g4/30)))


See edited answer, you should now see how to use if(): which is comprised of 3 parts: a test, do if true, do if false.

IT WORKED, THANK YOU SO MUCH
